# How can I save user logs in a phpMyAdmin database from a NAS My Cloud?

Tags: mysql, server, phpmyadmin, nas

I have a NAS that is full of files and I have installed phpMyAdmin on it and I want to create a table that will audit file usage on the NAS. I have 4 users on the NAS and I am hoping to get a SQL table that will look like this in the phpMyAdmin;

```
UserIPAddress, FileName, timeFileOpened, timeFileClosed
```

I would like this table to update automatically in the background and whenever I need to view the logs I can simply log inot phpMyAdmin and view the table.

please Help

Comment: Since phpMyAdmin is a graphical interface for administrators to manage a database server, it doesn't log this sort of thing in itself. Do you have some other logging source that will insert the data in to your MySQL/MariaDB database?

Comment: I'm not sure of any other source. I am using a WD my cloud PR4100 if that is any help.